# System of differential equations on Mathematica

Tags: math-software

I've been trying to solve a system of differential equations on Mathematica, and I wanted to know why this implementation does not work:

`f[t_]:= {x[t],y[t],z[t]}

v[t_]:= f'[t]

A = {a,b,c} 

DSolve[{f''[t]==k Cross[v[t],A],f[0]=={0,0,0},f,t]`

If I write the system explicitly, on the other hand, it works; why is that?
By explicitly I mean:

`DSolve[{x''[t] == k(c y'[t]-b z'[t]), y''[t]==k( -c x'[t] + a z'[t]), z''[t]==k( b x'[t]- a y'[t])},{x,y,z},t]`

And in this case I'm not able to input an initial value, thus ending up with a whole lot of costants which I don't really care about right now.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparison (==) does not Thread over lists; otherwise it would be impossible to compare lists. You want to use the function Thread:

```
In[8]:= Thread[{x, y, z} == {1, 2, 3}]
Out[8]= {x == 1, y == 2, z == 3}
```

In your case you will need

```
Join[Thread[f''[t]==k Cross[v[t],A]],Thread[f[0]=={0,0,0}]]
```

Finally, let me recommend the group [comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/topics?lnk=iggc) for Mathematica related questions.